# Разреженная матрица С++

Tags: c++

Подскажите как написать структуру сильно разреженной матрицы на С++.
Структура должна отображать индекс числа. Нули выводить не следует.

Вот примерно так, я это реализовал

```
struct Cell
    {
        int j;
        int data;
        Cell* next = nullptr;
    };

    struct Row
    {
        int i;
        Cell* scell = nullptr;
        Row* next = nullptr;
    };
    
    struct SparseMatrix
    {
        int m;
        int n;

        Row* srow = nullptr;
    };

    struct Vec {
        int n;
        Cell* scell = nullptr;
    };
```

Comment: Это очень общий вопрос. Уточните, пожалуйста, применение данной матрицы в вашей задаче. В общем случае если у вас очень большая и очень разреженная матрица, то можно использовать `std::map`.

Comment: в дополнение к вышеприведенному комменту хочу добавить, что если вы имеете дело с разреженными матрицами в конексте изображений, то стоит обратиться в `opencv` где уже существуют классы разреженных матриц

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не структура а весьма сложная и наукоемкая конструкция, сложность заключается в отображении последовательности  значений на пространство индексов , а так же оптимизация тех или иных операций (вставки значений, сложения, умножения матриц)

Если нужен готовый класс, можно подумать о внедрении OpenCV (`cv::SparseMat`) или обертки для библиотеки BLAS из boost ( `boost::numeric::ublas::mapped_matrix`, `...::compressed_matrix`) и\или совместимой с ней  mapped_matrix из ViennaCL.

Все они сравнительно медленны по отношению к реализациям использующим спец.вычислительные средства ( например , CUDA) По обработке на граф. процессоре есть достаточно статей, https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~aydin/spmm_europar2018.pdf